# How to convert an XML file to an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, xml

I have a directory which contains multiple XML files, lets say it contains the following 2:

```
<Record>
        <RecordID>Madird01</RecordID>
        <Location>Madird</Location>
        <Date>07-09-2020</Date>
        <Time>07u43m55s</Time>
        <Version>2.0.1</Version>
        <Version_2>v1.9</Version_2>
    <Max_30e>
        <I_25Hz_1s>56.40</I_25Hz_1s>
        <I_25Hz_2s>7.44</I_25Hz_2s>
    </Max_30e>
    <Max_30e>
        <I_75Hz_1s>1.56</I_75Hz_1s>
        <I_75Hz_2s>0.36</I_75Hz_2s>
    </Max_30e>
</Record>
```

And:

```
<Record>
        <RecordID>London01</RecordID>
        <Location>London</Location>
        <Date>07-09-2020</Date>
        <Time>08u53m45s</Time>
        <Version>2.0.1</Version>
        <Version_2>v1.9</Version_2>
    <Max_30e>
        <I_25Hz_1s>56.40</I_25Hz_1s>
        <I_25Hz_2s>7.44</I_25Hz_2s>
    </Max_30e>
    <Max_30e>
        <I_75Hz_1s>1.56</I_75Hz_1s>
        <I_75Hz_2s>0.36</I_75Hz_2s>
    </Max_30e>
</Record>
```

Now I want to convert this to an excel file which shows every XML file in horizontal order like this:
[image]

I tried to convert the XML to csv string first and then to Excel but I got stuck, there should be easier ways.

**This is my current code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

xml_root = r'c:\data\Desktop\Blue\XML-files'

for file in os.listdir(xml_root):
    xml_file_path = os.path.join(xml_root, file)
    
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

    for child in root:
        mainlevel = child.tag
        xmltocsv = ''
        for elem in root.iter():
            if elem.tag == root.tag:
                continue
            if elem.tag == mainlevel:
                xmltocsv = xmltocsv + '\n'
            xmltocsv = xmltocsv + str(elem.tag).rstrip() + str(elem.attrib).strip() + ';' + str(elem.text).rstrip() + ';'
```

Comment: This library can be your friend: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @floatingpurr that's only for Excel 2010 I have the latest version + I find that library quiet complex

Comment: It creates xlsx files. You shouldn't have problems with latest Excel. Here you can find even more resources: https://www.python-excel.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a csv file which is Excel friendly format.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from os import listdir


xml_lst = [f for f in listdir() if f.startswith('xml')]
fields = ['RecordID','I_25Hz_1s','I_75Hz_2s'] # TODO - add rest of the fields
with open('out.csv','w') as f:
  f.write(','.join(fields) + '\n')
  for xml in xml_lst:
    root = ET.parse(xml)
    values = [root.find(f'.//{f}').text for f in fields]
    f.write(','.join(values) + '\n')
```

output

```
RecordID,I_25Hz_1s,I_75Hz_2s
Madird01,56.40,0.36
London01,56.40,0.36
```

Comment: Im using XML files instead of XML strings. I have `ET.parse(xml_file_path)` and then I use `root=tree.getroot()` so after I do `root.text`  I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: You just need to replace *fromstring* with *parse*

Comment: That is what I have already but still the same error: `root = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
        values = [root.find(f'.//{f}').text for f in fields]` I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: What is the xml file path? Your problem may be there

Comment: That is the absolute filepath of the XML file. `ET.parse` creates an `elementtree` while `ET.fromstring` creates an Element.

Comment: Print it and see what is wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Its just the path of the xml files:
`c:\data\Desktop\Blue\XML-files\xmlfile_1`
`c:\data\Desktop\Blue\XML-files\xmlfile_2`

Comment: And the xml files are the same as in your question?

Comment: Yes they are the same but they are files instead of strings like in your case

Comment: In the **script folder** I have 2 xml files that startswith `xml` - the updated code read them and generate the csv. Let me know it your problem is solved.

Comment: I want it directly to Excel not csv please. Could you update your code?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to iterate over files in folder with similar names one of the ways could be make a pattern and use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). To make sure that returned path is file you can use [`isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).

Regarding XML, I see that basically you need to write values of every terminal tag in column with name of this tag. As you have various files you can create tag-value dictionaries from each file and store them into [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap). After all files processed you can use [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write all data into final csv file.

This method is much more safe and flexible then use static column names. Firstly program will collect all possible tag(column) names from all files, so in case if XML doesn't have such a tag or have some extra tags it won't throw an exception and all data will be saved.

Code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from glob import iglob
from os.path import isfile, join
from csv import DictWriter
from collections import ChainMap

xml_root = r"C:\data\Desktop\Blue\XML-files"
pattern = "xmlfile_*"
data = ChainMap()
for filename in iglob(join(xml_root, pattern)):
    if isfile(filename):
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        temp = {node.tag: node.text for node in root.iter() if not node}
        data = data.new_child(temp)

with open(join(xml_root, "data.csv"), "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, data)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data.maps[:-1])  # last is empty dict
```

---

**Upd.** If you want to use `xlsx` format instead of `csv` you have to use third-party library *(e.g. [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))*. Example of usage:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

...

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.append(list(data))  # write header
for row in data.maps[:-1]:
    ws.append([row.get(key, "") for key in data])
wb.save(join(xml_root, "data.xlsx"))
```

Comment: how do I write that exact same data.csv to Excel?

Comment: @Al-Andalus, what do you mean? You want `xlsx` format? Csv should be supported by excel

Comment: What line do I add after `writer.writerows(data.maps[:-1])` to make that csv file an Excel file?

Comment: @Al-Andalus, you can open `.csv` file using Excel, it is supported format.

Comment: I tried that but I get everything before the first comma inside 1 collumn. I prefer it to be directly an excel file then an csv file

Comment: @Al-Andalus, coma is a default delimiter, so it works as it supposed to work - *"everything before the first comma inside 1 collumn"*. You can use third-party library, e.g. [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to write result in `.xlsx` format. But I'd stay with `csv`, it should be enough.

Comment: Could you add that line of code using openpyxl Im afraid I need to use an other with open statement while I want to write it directly after the last line. PS: I gave you an upvote...

Comment: @Al-Andalus, I've added code which writes result to *xlsx* to my answer. For future: upvotes are not something that should motivate me or anybody else to do work for you, and you probably shouldn't use this as argument, it doesn't look good.

Comment: So the Excel block of code comes instead of the CSV code block. I guess you mean `data.xlsx` instead of `data.csv` I guess in your last block of code.

Comment: @Al-Andalus, yes, exactly.